# Recover "free space" on hard drive

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partition, disk-space, diskutil

How can I merge the free space on my MacBook with the rest of my hard drive? I tried to run Asahi then removed it

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the EFI partition, then extend the APFS container to include the free space. The commands are given below.

```
diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s3
diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0
```

The Eclectic Light Company has published an [article](https://eclecticlight.co/2021/01/14/m1-macs-radically-change-boot-and-recovery/) which includes an image of the macOS 11.1 Boot Disk Structure (M1 internal). Since the image is explicitly copyrighted, I will not include a copy of the image in this answer. What is important to note is that the image does not show an EFI partition. I assume the EFI partition shown in the OP's question was created when installing Linux and therefore should be removed.